# Two docker containers cannot communicate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices

I have two docker containers. One container is a database and the other is a web application.
Web application calls the database through this link http://localhost:7200. However, the web application docker container cannot reach the database container.

I tried this docker-compose.yml, but does not work:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    # will build ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    build: 
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    links:
      - graph-db
    depends_on:
     - graph-db
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - WAIT_HOSTS=graph-db:7200
    networks: 
      - backend

  graph-db:
    # will build ./docker/graph-db/Dockerfile
    build:
        ./docker/graph-db
    hostname: graph-db
    ports:
      - "7200:7200"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: "bridge"
```

**So I have two containers:**
web application: http://localhost:8080/reasoner and this container calls a database in http://localhost:7200 which resides in a different container.
However database container is not reachable by web container.

**SOLUTION**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    # will build ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    build: 
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
     - graph-db
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - WAIT_HOSTS=graph-db:7200


  graph-db:
    # will build ./docker/graph-db/Dockerfile
    build:
        ./docker/graph-db
    ports:
      - "7200:7200"
```

and replace http://localhost:7200 in web app code with http://graph-db:7200

Comment: Try changing hostname to localhost in graph-db

Comment: I'm assuming for your solution it also included the `network` sections you just didn't mention it? :)

Comment: It has been a long time since I have tried that. In docker-compose in the solution, I have no docker network. I remember that the containers are implicitly registered into the same docker network when running the docker-compose

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do not use localhost to communicate between containers. Networking is one of the namespaces in docker, so localhost inside of a container only connects to that container, not to your external host, and not to another container. In this case, use the service name, `graph-db`, instead of `localhost`, in your app to connect to the db.

Comment: By using http://graph-db:7200 in web application's code works! Thanks for the solution. 
Also, I removed the networks from the docker-compose.yml, and left links. I do not know if this is a good practice.

So now my web application's code will have http://graph-db:7200 for using docker containers; however, when I run it locally without docker containers, localhost is needed in the url. Of course, this is a different issue, I ll investigate that. Thanks for the solution for the docker issue.

Comment: @zoevas you don't need links, that a legacy feature that injects entries in the /etc/hosts file. That doesn't work when container IP's are changing from redeploys/updates/scaling. By default you'll get DNS on the network compose creates which resolves the service name. You'll see a network called `${project}_default` if you don't specify a network yourself.

Comment: ok, I removed links and still works. I suppose that the services can communicate because by default they belong to the same network as you said ${project}_default.

Comment: Just a question, hostname defined the name of the service right?

Comment: I'd recommend service name, not hostname. Each replica may have a unique hostname, but share the service name and DNS alias.

Answer (score 2):

Your db host is `graph-db`, and that name that you should use in database configuration in your app. eg: `http://graph-db:7200`

From docker network documentation (bridge networks - the default network driver in Docker):

> Imagine an application with a web front-end and a database back-end.
> If you call your containers **web** and **db**, the web container can connect
> to the db container at **db**, no matter which Docker host the application
> stack is running on.

Comment: I Tried to use hostname in my docker-compose. But still it fails to communicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310185/docker-compose-container-fails-to-read-the-application-running-in-different-cont