# Docker compose container fails to read the application running in different container and in same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml file which contains frontend,backend,testing,postgres and pgadmin container. The containers except testing are able to communicate each other. But the testing container fails to communicate with backend and frontend container in docker-compose.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: test-frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    networks:
      - test-network
    environment:
      # For the frontend can be applied only during the build! 
      # (while it's applied when TS is compiled)
      # You have to build manually without cache if one of those are changed at least for the prod mode.
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_API=http://localhost:8000/api/v1
      - REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=1234567dfghjjnfd
      - CI=true
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dev
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dev
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
       - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - test-network
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "dev@dev.com"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: dev
    volumes:
       - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
       - ./pgadmin-config/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - test-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  backend:
    container_name: test-backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    command: > 
      bash -c "alembic upgrade head
      && exec /start-reload.sh"
    networks:
      - test-network
    depends_on:
      - postgres  
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/.secret/secret.json
      - APP_DB_CONNECTION_STRING=postgresql+psycopg2://dev:dev@postgres:5432/postgres
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True
      - AUTH_ENABLED=True
      - CORS=*
      - GCP_ALLOWED_DOMAINS=*

  testing:
    container_name: test-testing
    build:
      context: ./testing
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./testing:/isp-app
    command: > 
      bash -c "/wait
      && robot ."
    networks:
      - test-network
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend  
    environment:
      - WAIT_HOSTS= frontend:3000, backend:8000 
      - WAIT_TIMEOUT= 3000
      - WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL=300
      - WAIT_HOST_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300
volumes:
    postgres:
    pgadmin:
      
networks:
    test-network:
        driver: bridge
```

All the containers are mapped to test-network. When the testing container tried to connect to frontend:3000 or backend:8000, it throws "Host [ backend:8000] not yet available"

How to fix it?

Comment: When using a frontend service ("frontend:3000"), do you call it from the host (your machine) or from within the container?

Comment: It will be called from testing service container... From host it works as localhost:3000

Comment: frontend and backend service communicates without any issue. Only testing service fails to communicate. I also tried to connect using localhost also.. It also fails

Comment: The extra spaces in the `WAIT_HOSTS=` line are throwing things off; it is trying to connect to a hostname `<space>backend` which doesn't resolve.  You can see the extra space in your error message too.  Does deleting the spaces in `WAIT_HOSTS` and `WAIT_TIMEOUT` help?

Comment: Nope... Getting the same error.

Comment: bro, How's it going? I met the same problem... can't find other container by container name...

Comment: Did you figure it out?  If you `sh` into test-testing can connect to other services' ports manually?

Comment: It didn't work.. I tried to connect to other service ports manually, but it fails